# How can I allow a regex to be blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a form that accepts only a valid email, or a blank email. I think it will be something along these lines:

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i OR ""
validates :email, format: { with: EMAIL_REGEX }
```

or maybe

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
BLANK_REGEX = 
validates :email, format: { with: EMAIL_REGEX OR BLANK_REGEX }
```

but I can't figure out the proper syntax. Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Comment: @sawa I wasn't aware, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach pointed by @avinash-raj is perfect. However you can use **allow_blank: true** in your validates. Your code should be like this:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i}, allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make your regex optional to make your regex to match blank email also.

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A(?:[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+)?\z/i
```

OR

```
EMAIL_REGEX = /^(?:[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+)?$/i
```

TO make a regex optional, enclose the whole regex inside a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and then add a `?` next to that group.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on that? How can I make a regex optional?

Comment: you could do like this `^(?:[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+|)$` also. `|` or operator helps to match the blank lines..